# How do I update my imageResponseSerializer from Alamofire to the 3.0 version?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have an imageResponseSerializer that I built following this tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial

I honestly don't really know how it works, so I was wondering if someone could help me update it to something that will work with Alamofire 3.0. Here is my code:

```
extension Alamofire.Request {

class func imageResponseSerializer() -> GenericResponseSerializer<UIImage> {
    return GenericResponseSerializer { request, response, data in

        guard let validData = data else {
            let failureReason = "Data could not be serialized. Input data was nil."
            let error = Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
            return .Failure(data, error)
        }

        if let image = UIImage(data: validData, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale) {
            return Result<UIImage>.Success(image)
        } else {
            return .Failure(data, Error.errorWithCode(.DataSerializationFailed, failureReason: "Unable to create image"))
        }

    }
}

    func responseImage(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result<UIImage>) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(responseSerializer: Request.imageResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: well I just want to create a UIImage from the data I'm retrieving. Nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your own image response serialization, you should switch over to using [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage). We built it so you wouldn't have to!

Comment: yeah that's what I ended up doing. Wasn't too hard to use. Thanks.